# AWS Golang Lambda handler function not getting called

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I have a Golang 1.18 program like:

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"

        "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    )

    func HandleRequest() error {
        fmt.Print("HandleRequest entered\n")
        return nil
    }

    func main() {
        fmt.Print("Starting HandleRequest\n")
        lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
    }
```

Which I've compiled in Linux, zip'ed up, and deployed to AWS Lambda with Go1.x runtime. When I "Test" my lambda via AWS UI, I see the `Starting handleRequest` print statement, but I don't see the `handleRequest entered` print startment. In the logs I see a line like `Task timed out after 30.03 seconds`.

I have no clue why it is timing out, or taking 30 seconds in order to start calling `handleRequest`. The handler function signature should be valid, according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html#golang-handler-signatures.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: The `handleRequest` function must be exported... that means it should be visible to the caller... you need to rename it to `HandleRequest`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html#golang-handler-signatures

Comment: @Chetan thanks but I tried and same result with a timeout.  This is deployed in a VPC, but I am not accessing any resources, as shown in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed an outbound security group rule to allow all traffic, although I dont know why (as I'm not making any outbound requests).